# Kendo UI Grid Cancel SaveChanges using a javascript confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way to cancel a `SaveChanges` event from the client side before to proceed with changes? I'm using a simple javascript native `confirm` dialog :

kendo grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<StrategyParameterModel>()
    .Name("strategyParameters")
    .Events(e => e.SaveChanges("onSave"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    { ... }
```

javascript:

```
 function onSave() {
     return confirm("Are you sure?");
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am of mind that the cancelation of the event would work since the event is raised prior to posting, however, I have not tried it and I am currently not able to test it. If it does it work then leave a comment and I will delete the answer.

```
 function onSave() {
     if(!confirm("Are you sure?"))
         e.preventDefault();
 };
```

Comment: considering you have to add the `e` parameter for the `onSave()` function, it works for preventing... all good